# Tikz: Declaring a function in tikzpicture is messing with my axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I am trying to create some diagrams illustrating Riemann sums and am having trouble getting my axis lines to be centered when I declare a function. Note: I am using some code I found online that requires the declaration of a function in order to generate the rectangles in the Riemann sum approximation and this is also taking place within a beamer slideshow.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,red]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{lily} 
\beamersetaveragebackground{brown!30!white}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}



\pgfplotsset{
    integral segments/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\integralsegments{#1}},
    integral segments=3,
    integral/.style args={#1:#2}{
        ybar interval,
        domain=#1+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2:#2+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2,
        samples=\integralsegments+1,
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2}
    }
}



\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}[c]{ }
\frametitle{Section 6.3: Area and the Definite Integral}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
%[color=black,/pgf/declare function={f=0.125*x^3-x^2+1.5*x + 3;}]
[
    axis lines=center,
    grid=major,
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-1.5,
    ymax=4.5,
    extra x ticks = {-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6}, 
    extra y ticks = {-1,1,2,3,4},
    no marks,
    axis line style={<->},
]
%\addplot [<->, smooth,black, thick, domain = -1:5] {f};
%\addplot [
%    red,
%    fill=red,
%    opacity=0.4,
%    integral segments=10,
%    integral=0:5
%] {f};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following: [image: nice set of centered axis lines] However, when I uncomment the portion of the code that plots the function and the Riemann sum, I get the following output: [image: which does not have the axis lines centered]

How can I keep my axis lines centered and keep the important parts of the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I did not even try out your code because you do not really define a function, so I cannot tell you what went wrong. However, if you define a true function with an explicit `x` dependence, there is no problem.

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,red]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usecolortheme{lily} 
\beamersetaveragebackground{brown!30!white}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}



\pgfplotsset{
    integral segments/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\integralsegments{#1}},
    integral segments=3,
    integral/.style args={#1:#2}{
        ybar interval,
        domain={#1+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2}:{#2+((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2},
        samples=\integralsegments+1,
        x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-((#2-#1)/\integralsegments)/2}
    }
}



\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}[c]{ }
\frametitle{Section 6.3: Area and the Definite Integral}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[color=black,
declare function={f(\x)=0.125*\x*\x*\x-\x*\x+1.5*\x + 3;},
    axis lines=center,
    grid=major,
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-1.5,
    ymax=4.5,
    extra x ticks = {-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6}, 
    extra y ticks = {-1,1,2,3,4},
    no marks,
    axis line style={<->},
]
\addplot [stealth-stealth,smooth, black, thick, domain = -1:5] {f(x)};
\addplot [
   red,
   fill=red,
   opacity=0.4,
   integral segments=10,
   integral=0:5
] {f(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whether you read my code or not, that did the trick! Thank you!